# mySQL - combined tables with primary key, but want to insert into combined table using titles

Tags: mysql

I've searched and looked alot into the different join and union commands for mySQL but cannot find a solution to my problem regarding the code undernearth.

I only worked with mySQL for a couple of days trying to learn mySQL, HTML, CSS, PHP, javascript, python and more to create my own servers with databases, webpages, backup, make my home to be interconnected etc. All help is very appreciated! 'Takk' in advance! :)

```
create database cinema;
use  cinema;

create table cinema.genre (
    genre_code varchar(3) not null,
    genre varchar(45) null,
    primary key (genre_code) );

create table cinema.movie (
    movie_id int not null auto_increment,
    genre varchar(3) null,
    released int(4) null,
    title varchar(45) not null,
    name_director varchar(45) null,
    primary key(movie_id),
    constraint FK_genre foreign key (genre) references cinema.genre(genre_code) );


create table movie_halls (
    hall_id int not null auto_increment,
    hall_name varchar(45) not null,
    spaces int not null,
    primary key (hall_id) );

create table overview (
    cinema_per_id int not null auto_increment,
    date_time datetime not null, #1000-01-01 00:00:00
    hall_id int not null,
    movie_id int not null,
    number_people int null,
    primary key (cinema_per_id) );

insert into cinema.genre values
('COM', 'Comedy'),
('ACT', 'Action'),
('DRA', 'Drama'),
('HOR', 'Horror');

insert into cinema.movie (genre, released, title, name_director) values
('COM', 2010, '2 goats', 'Speilberg, Peter'),
('ACT', 2012, 'Fast5', 'Dramaqueen'),
('DRA', 1995, 'Status quo', 'Turtle, Ninja'),
('ACT', 1950, 'Joker', 'Man, Spider');

insert into movie_halls (hall_name, spaces) values
('Darth Vader', 200),
('Princess Leila', 150),
('Yoda', 1999),
('Obi-Wan Kenobi', 1920);
```

This is what I would like to input into overview (to make it easy and not to remember all the ids of movies and halls.

```
insert into overview (date_time, hall_id, movie_id, number_people) values
(2018-04-06 20:00:00, 'Darth Vader', 'Fast5', 120),
(2018-04-06 20:00:00, 'Yoda', 'Joker', 1500),
(2018-04-06 21:30:00, 'Obi-Wan Kenobi', '2 goats', 1200);
```

and be stored like this:
[image: How it should be stored]

and if I now select overview after insertion I would like to see following (don't mind the datetime format - just excel mixing it up):
[image: Picture dump from excel]

I'm not sure if this is possible, or if my general modeling of my database is what is at fault. Any clarification and help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As variant you can use subqueries for inserting

```
insert into overview (date_time, hall_id, movie_id, number_people) values
('2018-04-06 20:00:00', (select hall_id from movie_halls where hall_name='Darth Vader'), (select movie_id from movie where title='Fast5'), 120),
('2018-04-06 20:00:00', (select hall_id from movie_halls where hall_name='Yoda'), (select movie_id from movie where title='Joker'), 1500),
('2018-04-06 21:30:00', (select hall_id from movie_halls where hall_name='Obi-Wan Kenobi'), (select movie_id from movie where title='2 goats'), 1200)
```

And then use a query with `JOIN`. For example

```
SELECT
  o.*,
  h.hall_name,
  m.title AS movie_title
FROM overview o
JOIN movie_halls h ON o.hall_id=h.hall_id
JOIN movie m ON o.movie_id=m.movie_id
ORDER BY o.date_time
```